# SFMC SQL Query to retrieve contacts that have not clicked any email sent in the last 6 months?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Can someone validate the following query for me?

I am trying to retrieve all subscribers that were sent an email in the last 6 months and have not clicked any?

```
SELECT distinct s.SubscriberID     
FROM _Sent s 
WHERE s.EventDate > dateadd(day,-180,getdate()) 
AND s.SubscriberID NOT IN (
  SELECT o.SubscriberID
  FROM _Click o
  WHERE o.EventDate >  dateadd(day,-180,getdate())
)
AND s.SubscriberID is not null
```

The targeted data extensions contains: `SubscriberId` field, am I right to think the Contacts added to the DE are those that were sent an email in the last 6 months but not clicked it because they do not exist in the `_Click` data view?

Comment: SFMC data views (_Sent and _Click) only retain data for the past 6 months, so your filters for dates are unnecessary. Other than that, your query seems good.  I usually recommend using LEFT JOINS instead of IN or EXISTS - but is not necessary